# DataGrid: Allow edit for second row only after saving changes for the first row

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` whose `ItemsSource` is binding to a property of type `ObservableCollection(of MY_TYPE)` of the ViewModel. Additionaly, in the ViewModel I also have an property called `SelectedTarget` which is binding to the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid` (the type is of course MY_TYPE ).

Now what I want to achieve is: The user can move the cursor to another row, ONLY IF the previous row (the `SelectedTarget`) doesn't have any changes, otherwise he must save those changes at first. But I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE

Here is my xaml code and ViewModel property, it is like Sheridan has suggested.

the xaml

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectionMode="Single"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                       VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTarget, Mode=TwoWay}"                        
                       SelectionUnit="FullRow">
```

And the property in ViewModel:

```
Public Property SelectedTarget As MY_TYPE
        Get
            Return _selectedTarget
        End Get
        Set(value As MY_TYPE)
            If _selectedTarget Is Nothing OrElse (_selectedTarget.Status <> Status.Editing AndAlso _selectedTarget.Status <> Status.New) Then
                _selectedTarget = value
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTarget")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _selectedTarget As MY_TYPE
```

I have checked, that when the `Status` of `SelectedTarget` is Editing, it won't change `SelectedTarget` itself. However, this doesn't stop the values in another row from getting changed. The cursor gets moved to another row anyway, but I am not sure whether that means my `SelectedItem` binding doesn't work properly. On the other hand, if I don't set the binding of `SelectedItem` in `DataGrid` at all, the values still get changed in a second row even if I don't save the change in the first one. It kind of makes sense since each row is binding to one item by nature anyway.

Comment: you could bind to an flag (bool)

Comment: @WiiMaxx Could you give me more details? In MY_TYPE class, I do have one Enum flag to indicate the status (Valid, Edit and New), but I can't think of the way of using it in this situation. I kinda have the feeling that this should be simple though

Comment: i edited my Answer now it should fit your need's ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do this. i know its ugly but you get the idea :)

### Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new VM();
    }
}

public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> mySource;

    private MyItem myTarget;

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MySource
    {
        get { return mySource; }
        set { mySource = value; }
    }

    public MyItem MyTarget
    {
        get { return myTarget; }
        set
        {
            if (myTarget == null)
                myTarget = value;
            else if (myTarget.IsSaved)
                myTarget = value;

            INotifyPropertyChanged("MyTarget");
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        mySource = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "1", Text2 = "8" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "2", Text2 = "7" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "3", Text2 = "6" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "4", Text2 = "5" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "5", Text2 = "4" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "6", Text2 = "3" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "7", Text2 = "2" });
        mySource.Add(new MyItem { Text1 = "8", Text2 = "1" });
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged
}

public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text1;

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return text1; }
        set
        {
            text1 = value;
            isSaved = false;

            INotifyPropertyChanged("Text1");
            INotifyPropertyChanged("IsSaved");
        }
    }

    private string text2;

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return text2; }
        set
        {
            text2 = value;
            isSaved = true;

            INotifyPropertyChanged("Text2");
            INotifyPropertyChanged("IsSaved");
        }
    }

    private bool isSaved = true;

    public bool IsSaved
    {
        get { return isSaved; }
        set
        {
            isSaved = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => IsSaved));
        }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

### XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MyTarget, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>

                <!-- for your other items-->
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition  Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.IsSaved, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="false"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSaved}" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

</DataGrid>
```

### EDIT

I found a way to show the Row's i hope you like it :)

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>

                <!-- for your other items-->
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition  Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.IsSaved, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="false"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSaved}" Value="true"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It kind of works. But is there any way not to make other rows hidden (when the SelectedItem has changes)? I guess that's what my problem is: I think my SelectedItem binding is working correctly. However, it doesn't stop other rows from being modified. While in your solution, when the SelectedItem has changes, all other rows are hidden so then can't be changed any more. But your solution is definitely a valid one and has interesting effect

Comment: @tete actually i was trying to bind to the `IsReadyOnly` Value from the `DataGridCell` which i doesn't worked also for the `DataGridRow` it doesn't worked like i expected but maybe you are able to bind to one of them so it will work like you want :)

Comment: Yeah, I see your point and that's also what's bothers me. But currently I am happy with your solution :)

Comment: @WiiMaxx you can only apply IsReadOnly on an entire column. The only way I could figure out to get around this limitation was we set the background color of the cells based on bindings that determine whether it should be an editable cell. Then we use the BeginningEdit event to check the background color of the cell and cancel if it's supposed to be uneditable. A similar solution could work here as well.

Comment: @WiiMaxx your edited version is definitely a working solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is for you to create some basic framework that will tell you whether an item has changes or not. This can be achieved easily using another instance of your `MY_TYPE` class and by simply comparing the values of each property.

The next stage is to stop the user from changing the selected item if they have made changes to the current object. If you have correctly data bound your `SelectedTarget` property, then you should be able to stop the user from changing the current row something like this:

```
public MY_TYPE SelectedTarget
{
    get { return selectedTarget; }
    set 
    {
        if (!SelectedTarget.HasChanges)
        {
            selectedTarget = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTarget"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, when the user saves the current item, then you need to synchronise your two objects to signify  that there are no changes any longer and then the user will be able to change the record again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's basically what I have done, but so far it doesn't work. I added some code in my original post, please see what else I need to do. My feeling is either the SelectedItem is not correctly bind, or it doesn't need the SelectedItem to be altered to make those changes (because each row is binding to one item in the collection whatsoever)

Comment: It doesn't *look* like that's what you're doing. And what do you mean by 'maybe the `SelectedItem` is not correctly data bound?' If *your* `Binding` is not working, then only *you* can tell us that.

Comment: Can you see what I am doing wrong in my update code? What I did: 1) set the binding of `SelectedItem` in `DataGrid` to `SelectedTarget` and 2) in the xaml, set the `SelectedTarget` only if the current item's status is Valid. I think the second part is the same as in your code. And when I say "maybe the binding of SelectedItem" is not working correctly, I mean even though the `SelectedTarget` is not changed because the IF condition doesn't hold, but the cursor in `DataGrid` is indeed moved to another row. And I don't know whether that is the correct behavior of `SelectedItem`.

Comment: And like I mentioned, if I don't do the binding of `SelectedItem` at all, I can modify the values in more than one row, since by its nature each row is binding to one item in the ItemsSource collection. Nothing (and should not) stops the modification of a second row. It kind of makes sense. So does adding a SelectedItem binding change this behavior?